# Como chamar um script com argumentos?

Tags: ruby

Eu estou um pouco acima do peso, e pesquisando no [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone), eu descobri como calcular meu gasto calórico, através do batimento cardíaco.

Então eu criei o seguinte script:

```
bpm = 150
massa = 70
idade = 20 # hahaha
tempo = 30
sexo = 'm'

def calcular(bpm, massa, idade, tempo, sexo)
  if sexo == 'm'
    ((-55.0969 + (0.6309 * bpm) + (0.1988 * massa) + (0.2017 * idade)) / 4.184) * tempo
  elsif sexo == 'f'
    ((-20.4022 + (0.4472 * bpm) - (0.1263 * massa) + (0.074 * idade)) / 4.184) * tempo
  end
end

p calcular(bpm, massa, idade, tempo, sexo)
```

> Execução:
>   ruby gasto_calorico.rb
>   412.19956978967497

Eu gostaria de eliminar a definição de variáveis, e chamar o *script* da seguinte maneira:

> ruby gasto_calorico 150 70 20 30 m

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode "capturar" parâmetros por linha de comando através da constante `ARGV`.

Quando você chamar `ruby gasto_calorico 150 70 20 30 m`, faça:

```
unless ARGV.length == 5 #se os parametros não foram passados corretamente
  puts "Uso: ruby gasto_calorico -bpm -massa -idade -tempo -sexo"
  exit
end
params = ["bpm", "massa", "idade", "tempo", "sexo"]

#iteração do array ARGV
for i in (0...ARGV.length)
  puts params[i] + " => " + ARGV[i]
end
```

A classe [GetoptLong](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html) automatiza esse trabalho pra você e te da outras funcionalidades.